# Replace with default value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know if there is an easier way to replace a value with other when it is NaN, other than:

```py
var = a if not pd.isnull(a) else b
```

The idea would be to avoid having to have to use the variable `a`

Answer (score 3):

Simplier is use [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) if working with scalars:

```
var = a if pd.notna(a) else b
```

In column use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].mask(df['col'].notna(), a)

df.loc[df['col'].notna(), 'col'] = a
```